# Romanian Mathematical Olympiad (Diophantine Equation)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Solve the equation in positive integers $x,y,z$ $$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}.$$

The following is thee solution given by the author is as follows:

[image]

I have a question regarding this solution. Answers to it will be much appreciated.

1. If $x=2,$ then $$\frac{2}{y}\geq \frac{1}{10}\Rightarrow y\leq 20.$$ But we also know that $$\frac{1}{y}< \frac{1}{10}\Rightarrow 10< y\leq 20.$$ If this logic is true then when $x=3$ we must have $15<y\leq 30$, but clearly that is not the case. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Taking into account that $x\le y\le z$

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a typo to me. If $x = 3$, then we have $$\frac1y+\frac1z = \frac35-\frac13 = \frac{4}{15}$$ This implies that $\frac1y+\frac1z > \frac4{16} = \frac14$, so we must have $y < 8$. At the same time, $3 = x \leq y$. Thus we have $y \in \{3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$.